# Autoloading 'Session' library in Codeigniter shows warnings

Tags: php, codeigniter

I installed the latest version of codeigniter (Version 3.0.3) and it was working perfectly showing the welcome page. But when I tried to autoload the the session and database library it is showing up two errors.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Screenshot:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q7fp.png]

Please help.

Comment: have you included session_start(); in your config file?

Comment: no. when I included it, it is showing the same error one more time.

Comment: With codeigniter you do not need to use session_start() refer user guide.

Comment: no, the error may occur if you have included it. So asking just to confirm you should not. Try Touqeer Shafi' solution

Comment: I haven't used session_start(); anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your php has configured with auto session start. you can disable this by updating your `php.ini` file

```
session.auto_start = 0
```

Hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: find `session.auto_start` in php.ini if it's 1 then do 0, 1 means session is in auto_start mode.

Comment: Well i don't think it's the permanent solution but on this line you can add `@session_start()` it will remove the warning that you are getting. https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/Session.php#L140

Comment: I updated my php.ini file and restarted wamp. Now the warnings disappeared. ThankYou :)